# web2py, one to many, not required relationship

Tags: python, web2py

Consider 2 tables in the web2py python web framework.

The default `auth_user`

and this one:

```
b.define_table(
    'artwork',
    Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user', required=False),
    Field('name'),
    Field('description', 'text')
    )
```

Now, when I go to the Database Administration in (appadmin), I would expect the `user_id` to be optional. If I let the selection drop down empty, when manually entering an entry in the artwork table, it says : "value not in database" which seams against the `required=False` statement.

I would like to be able to insert an artwork entry without `user_id`

Can someone help me resolve this one? Thx a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a reference field, by default it gets a `requires=IS_IN_DB(...)` validator. The `requires` attribute is enforced at the level of forms, whereas the `required` attribute is enforced at the level of the DAL. To override the default form validator, you can do:

```
Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user', requires=None)
```

or alternatively,

```
Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user',
      requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.id',
                                    db.auth_user._format)))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony's answer was right, however, nowadays [it is no longer needed to explicitly write the `IS_EMPTY_OR(...)` part for a referenced field, because it would be set automatically since web2py 2.16.x or later](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/R-2.16.0b1/gluon/dal.py#L71-L72).